# PHP SimpleXML Error Message

Tags: php, simplexml

```
Warning:  main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists
```

I am loading a ml file via `simplexml_load_file`, it sometimes has values for an attribute and sometimes does not.

Usage:

```
$value = $xml->Name->arttributes();

Echo $value;
```

how do I error check to see if there is a value without getting a warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it the attributes() method not returning a value?  It looks like it may be the $xml->Name that isn't set.  Try checking if $xml->Name is set:

```
if( isset($xml->Name) )
      $value = $xml->Name->attributes();
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to check that the node actually exists before you use any method from it, e.g.

```
if (isset($xml->Name))
{
    $value = $xml->Name->attributes();
}
```

Comment: ahh you beat me!  I second this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
</movies>
XML;
?>

<?php
include 'example.php';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* Access the <rating> nodes of the first movie.
 * Output the rating scale, too. */
foreach ($xml->movie[0]->rating as $rating) {
    switch((string) $rating['type']) { // Get attributes as element indices
    case 'thumbs':
        echo $rating, ' thumbs up';
        break;
    case 'stars':
        echo $rating, ' stars';
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

So far, we have only covered the work of reading element names and their values. SimpleXML can also access element attributes. Access attributes of an element just as you would elements of an array.

Answer (score 0):

i think doing:

```
$attributeValue = isset($xml->attributes()->attributeName) ? $xml->attributes()->attributeName : null;
```